# Adding 16 to pointer?

Tags: c, encryption, aes

Was looking at TinyAES(https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c/blob/master/aes.c) , and I came across a snippet of code that I don't understand.

Assuming AES-128(meaning 16 byte key, and block size), wouldn't adding 16 to the output result in 0, since the for loop will only iterate once?

Main AES-CBC encryption function.

```
for (i = 0; i < 16; i += 16)
  {
    XorWithIv(input);
    memcpy(output, input, BLOCKLEN);
    state = (state_t*)output;
    Cipher();
    Iv = output;
    input += BLOCKLEN;
    output += BLOCKLEN;
    //printf("Step %d - %d", i/16, i);
  }
```

Comment: It looks like the loop body will only be executed once, with `i` being `0`.

Comment: This question fools us because it already partly, and incorrectly, replaced variables in the code. This is not the code found in the source.

Comment: @IngoBürk.: Yes that's why referred the repo and it explained all.

Comment: Where did you find this code? When I open the link, I cannot find this exact snippet. Line 538 comes close but is not a full match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output` is a pointer. In this case `output+=16` could mean `output` is zero, or even worse, it could be out of bound. But you should have saved another pointer which points the very beginning of encrypted output.

Example:

```
uint8_t buffer[32]={0};
uint8_t *output = buffer;
...
for(i = 0; i < 32; i += 16)
{
    XorWithIv(input);

    //changing output is the same as changing buffer from index i to i + BLOCKLEN
    memcpy(output, input, BLOCKLEN); 

    state = (state_t*)output;
    Cipher();
    Iv = output;
    input += BLOCKLEN;
    output += BLOCKLEN; //<== prepare to change the next block in buffer
}
```

In this example `output` is modified twice. It is now pointing to `buffer[32]` which is out of bound. However `buffer` is safely keeping the encrypted result.

Answer (score 1):

It's the **length of the input** not the key. Key length is determined using macro.

If you have length of input as `16` then yes just once it will execute.

We are not adding 16 to the output of result. Check the algorithm carefully.